# Why is Residential mortgage not traded in a money market?

Tags: mortgage, money-market

Which of the following instruments is not traded in a money market?

A) Residential mortgages.

B) U.S. Treasury Bills.

C) Negotiable bank certificates of deposit.

D) Commercial paper.

The answer is A. I thought residential mortgages can be securitized and traded in a money market, so why are residential mortgages not traded in a money market?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When residential mortgages are securitized in Collateralized Debt Obligations or CDOs, the CDO is a [member of the set of](https://www.nakedcapitalism.com/2007/09/some-money-market-funds-have-large.html) "commercial paper".

So you're partially right: a derivative of residential mortgages can be in a money market fund.  The "gotcha" in the question is that a whole base mortgage can not.

Comment: CDOs are not commercial paper - commercial paper is very short-term debt issues by companies.

Comment: @DStanley the link I used uses the phrase "CDO commercial paper" throughout, the first use "CDO commercial paper, often loaded with subprime debt, pays higher returns than corporate paper, and it paid as much as 6.5 percent in August".  Provide a high quality alternative link and I will edit (or feel free to create a separate answer).

Answer (score 3):

And to answer the question you asked: Because a residentual mortgage OUTSIDE of a securitized pool is neither standardized in any means (interest rate, duration, size). Noone wants to deal with a market for 10 million different mortgages, one each. All regular markets require some standardization or at least "buckets" that are large enough to handle the overhead of trading (i.e. a pool of 1 billion worth of mortgages have the same overhead in paperwork for trading than a single mortgage).

And once you securitize it, it is not a mortgage anymore but a commercial paper.

Comment: While there are bespoke mortgages, the "Fannie Mae/Freddy Mac Uniform Instrument" is pretty close to being standardized, so much that when you hear the term "conforming mortgage" it is to this standard that the loan conforms.  It's this standardization that enables the securitization.

Comment: Yeah, but the individual mortgage is still not standardized. No mortgage is replaceable with another one - which kills any idea of a market.